# -bash: export: not a valid identifier

Tags: android, macos, bash, cordova

I'm incredibly new to mobile application development and opted for the HTML/CSS/JavaScript approach via Cordova. I'm encountering this error when trying to amend my PATH and ANDROID_HOME in my .bash_profile and exporting either $PATH or $HOME:

```
-bash: export: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/tools:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools': not a valid identifier
```

I can see a space at the start of the path there but I've checked the .bash_profile and there is no space to be removed? After reading around I thought I'd check the .bashrc to see if a space is being thrown in from somewhere else, but apparently:

```
.bashrc does not exist
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this and I appreciate any help given!

Comment: What does the line in your `.bash_profile` look like? It should be something like `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:...` and not `export /usr/local/bin:...`

Comment: Hey @Jesper thanks for chiming in and bearing with my noobness here. The lines in my .bash_profile are as follows: `export ANDROID_HOME=/Development/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

Comment: Change `${PATH}` to `$PATH` without the `{}`

Answer (score 2):

The text `not a valid identifier` is complaining about an *identifier* that's set to that given value. That's *often* caused by improper use of `$` on the *left* side of an assignment, something like:

```
export $PATH=something
```

It *should* instead be:

```
export PATH=something
```

If that's not the case, check for spaces on either side of the `=`. Having those, most likely after the `=` can also cause this issue you're seeing.

When appending to the path, the syntax looks like:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/something
```

or:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

---

If you're really interested in seeing why the export is failing, a trick I often use is to change:

```
export xyzzy=$plugh/folder
```

into something that echos it first:

```
echo "[export xyzzy=$plugh/folder]"
export xyzzy=$plugh/folder
```

That way, I can see *exactly* how the command will be interpreted after substitutions have taken place. The other possibility there is to add `set -x` and `set +x` around the `export` line since that will cause the `bash` shell to echo the statement before executing it.

Sometimes I'll just put `set -x` near the top of the script so that *all* commands are echoed before execution but that requires a bit of searching to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I edited the .bash_profile to reflect your recommendations and haven't seen a change. If I do `export $HOME` I get similar error: `-bash: export: '/Users/Appa': not a valid identifier`

Comment: @nlw13, no, it's because your doing `export $HOME` when the correct way is `export HOME`.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. I changed `$PATH` to `PATH` and when attempting to open the .bash_profile I now receive a `-bash: open: command not found` error?

Comment: @nlw13, that sounds like it may be a different problem, you should ask a separate question if so, since that's the way SO works. Note that you should only have removed the `$` on the _left_ of the `=`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue using comments from Jesper in this post. I edited my `.bash_profile` to reflect the following:

`export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Appa/Development/android-sdk-macosx export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`